# CSS Source maps doesn't report the correct line when using nested selectors

Tags: css, gruntjs, less, source-maps

When I have sub-selectors (indented selectors) the line reported in Chrome Dev Tools when inspecting the sub-selector, is not the correct line but the line of its ancestor.

```
[1] #main {
[2]  max-width: 500px;
[3]  color: white;
[4]  .sub-container {
[5]    color: blue;
[6]  }
[7] }
```

inspecting `.sub-container` reports `[1]` instead of `[4]`.

Is there something wrong with how my maps are generated, or is it a flaw of LESS?

Comment: it is a bug in Chrome, see: https://github.com/less/less.js/issues/2033